# How can I make my radio checkbox's only be allowed one check per row in my table

Tags: php, ajax, radio-button

I'm having an issue where I'm using three radio's for three different options in my database. I'm trying to use UserLevel (3, 2 or 1 | 3 means Admin, 2 means Staff and 1 means Member). I made it so that when the specific radio is checked, it updates that users database query. But*, it's making the checkbox vertically in a set ( they're running downwards so only 1 can be selected in each vertical column). I want it so for each users **ROW**, it allows only one to be checked.

I have a picture of what I mean here :

[image: checkbox's are in a set (vertical) instead of horizontally for each clients row. I want it the other way around.]

***My code :***

```
<td style="border: 1px solid #eee; text-align: center; font-size: 11px;"  onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'userLevel','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);">
<input name="admin" class="admin" type="radio" value="<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>" <?php if ($faq[$k]["userLevel"] == 3){?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>>
<input name="staff" class="staff" type="radio" value="<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>" <?php if ($faq[$k]["userLevel"] == 2){?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>>
<input name="member" class="member" type="radio" value="<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>" <?php if ($faq[$k]["userLevel"] == 1){?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>>
```

Comment: I. Logic, for radio button, the name should be equal for all choices. So, does not use 'admin/staff/member' names, but something like `name="rights[<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>"`

Comment: @GeorgesO. Oh yeah :) Life saver my friend. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I. Logic, for radio button, the name should be equal for all choices. So, does not use 'admin/staff/member' names, but something like `name="rights[<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>"` Thanks to [Georges O.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7065748/georges-o)

**I needed to create different names for each radio checkbox.
Now it works like a charm.**